# Is it possible to replace "he"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to replace **he** with another word for better understanding of the sentence? What word/words could it be to say it naturally? I think to repeat "his grandfather" isn't best choice.

> He visits his grandfather but **he** [his grandfather] can’t visit him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ivan visits his grandfather but his grandfather can’t visit him.

Usual and idiomatic.

> Ivan visits his grandfather but he, the grandfather, can’t visit him.

Those are two ways to do this.

Less used and more formal (as in a legal document)

> He visits his grandfather but the latter can’t visit him.

Comment: No rule as such, it's used for highlighting quotes. If you want, you can delete the <  sign.

Answer (score 0):

One can almost always write around a pronoun. There is no one way to do it, it depends on the particular sentence and the meaning which the writer wants to convey.

In most cases a pronoun has a referent or antecedent, the person or thing that the pronoun refers to. One can generally use the referent instead of the pronoun. Sometimes this makes a clearer sentence, as it does in the example in the question. Sometimes it makes a poor, wordy sentence,. Then  some other way of avoiding the pronoun should be used if one wants to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

"he" is wrong because of the ambiguity induced.  Indeed, "He visits his grandfather but his grandfather can’t visit him" is correct.  This does not sound unnatural to a native English speaker.  It is precise and unambiguous.  Whenever there is the slightest ambiguity, or the chance of a misplaced modifier, ALWAYS opt for the longer, unambiguous form to avoid trouble.

Comment: First you say he is wrong; then you says its correct. Sort of confusing.